# Java method defining

Tags: java, methods

I'm working on an assignment and its our first time doing methods. I'm trying to create the method below but it keeps saying void is not a valid type. The name greeting it says is an illegal modifier and its saying I need a semicolon after the parentheses. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong I'm doing it as I see in all the examples I've looked at.

```
public static void greeting(){
        String greet = "This program will play 3 games of rock paper scissors with you.\n\n"+
                          "It will ask you for your choice and then randomly generate a choice for the computer.\n\n"+
                          "After all 3 games you will be shown the total results.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, greet, "Greeting",1);

    }
```

Here's the full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RPS_Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        public static void greeting(){
            String greet = "This program will play 3 games of rock paper scissors with you.\n\n"+
                           "It will ask you for your choice and then randomly generate a choice for the computer.\n\n"+
                           "After all 3 games you will be shown the total results.";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, greet, "Greeting",1);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok I changed it to this and it works. Kind of confuses me though cause it seems like the methods I'm going to use should be written and then called below.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class RPS_Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        greeting();

    }

    public static void greeting(){
        String greet = "This program will play 3 games of rock paper scissors with you.\n\n"+
                       "It will ask you for your choice and then randomly generate a choice for the computer.\n\n"+
                       "After all 3 games you will be shown the total results.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, greet, "Greeting",1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you put the method inside a `class` body?

Comment: I created a new class and put it inside the main method.  Not sure if that is considered in a class body or not.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Can you provide your whole code?

Comment: Move it to outside the `main` method. You cannot nest method declarations like that.

Comment: Java does not support nested methods, place it outside.

Comment: Yup like others said, you need to move it out of the main method

Comment: Ok ok thanks.  So then the main method is just empty?

Comment: @J_Farb, yes. You need to define methods in class and call them from other method (in your example from main method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your method outside of main method and call it from main like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class RPS_Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        greeting();
    }

    public static void greeting() {
        String greet = "This program will play 3 games of rock paper scissors with you.\n\n" +
                "It will ask you for your choice and then randomly generate a choice for the computer.\n\n" +
                "After all 3 games you will be shown the total results.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, greet, "Greeting", 1);
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need `import java.util.*;` library in your code.

Comment: Although the import statement is unnecessary in the provided code, it may be redacted. Another method may be using it, thus it may be not shown. :-p

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, it's true. But TS said that "I'm working on an assignment and its our first time doing methods". So, I think there is no other code . :)

Comment: There's going to be 3 methods

Comment: @J_Farb, you can create even 1000 methods. All you need is to write them inside of class and call from other method. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got to put everything in a class, make a main method, and call your method from the main method, like this:

```
public class Greeting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        greeting();
    }

    public static void greeting(){
        String greet = "This program will play 3 games of rock paper scissors with you.\n\n"+
                      "It will ask you for your choice and then randomly generate a choice for the computer.\n\n"+
                      "After all 3 games you will be shown the total results.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, greet, "Greeting",1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you name the file `RPSGame.java` because Java conventions use CamelCase for class names.

You cannot nest methods inside other methods.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

// Avoid using '_' (underscore) in the filename/classname because of conventions.
public class RPSGame {
    // Define greeting
    public static void greeting() {
        String greet = "This program will play 3 games of rock paper scissors with you.\n\n"+
                       "It will ask you for your choice and then randomly generate a choice for the computer.\n\n"+
                       "After all 3 games you will be shown the total results.";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, greet, "Greeting",1);
    }

    // The main() method is the entry point into your class, call your methods here.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        greeting(); // Call greeting.
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can nest methods inside other methods but it's typically done when defining a delegate.

Comment: @DelmerNicholson to my knowledge, delegates are not supported in Java.

Comment: They are. It's used in event-driven programming such as GUIs

Comment: @DelmerNicholson You may be thinking of implementing a class in-line and defining what that interface's methods should do...? Those are still not nested methods as such is the case in i.e. Python, JavaScript, or other interpreted languages.

Comment: @DelmerNicholson That is more reflective programming than actually defining a method inside of another method. This digresses from the main issue in question. I understand delegates. What you are explaining is more of [java.awt.geom.Point2D](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/awt/geom/Point2D.java#Point2D)'s `Float` and `Double` implementation via delegation.

Comment: @ Mr. Polywhirl  You're welcome to comment but please don't tell me what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot define a method inside a method,you can only call a method inside a method.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RPS_Game {

    public static void greeting(){
        String greet = "This program will play 3 games of rock paper scissors with you.\n\n"+
                       "It will ask you for your choice and then randomly generate a choice for the computer.\n\n"+
                       "After all 3 games you will be shown the total results.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, greet, "Greeting",1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        greeting();

    }
}
```